# Formula doesn't work for clicker game

Tags: javascript, html

```
 const buydankMiner1 = () => {

  if (borkCoins >= dankMiner.cost) {
dankMiner.qt += 1;
borkCoins -= dankMiner.cost;
  dankMiner.cost = Math.floor(Math.pow(dankMiner.cost, 1.05) / 1.18); 
 displayScreen()
} else {
  alert("Insufficient funds!");
}
};

  const buydankMiner5 = () => {

  if (borkCoins >= dankMiner.cost * 5) {
dankMiner.qt += 5;
borkCoins -= dankMiner.cost * 5;
 dankMiner.cost = Math.floor(Math.pow(dankMiner.cost * 5, 1.05) / 1.18); 
 displayScreen();
} else {
  alert("Insufficient funds!");
}
};
```

The code above is from a clicker game I'm attempting to make. There are two buttons that either buy 1 "dankMiner" or five of it. What I tried to do was increase the cost of a said "dankMiner" each time it is bought, hence the formula that first raises it to the power of 1.05 and divides it to 1.18. It works when I buy one "dankMiner," however when I do the option of buying five of it, the cost of it is not the same as when I click on the buy 1 option five times.

For example, clicking on the buy 1 option fifteen times results to the next one costing 77. However, clicking the buy 5 option three times results to the next one costing over 11,000.

Comment: because your formula is wrong, it is not 5 times the cost.....

Comment: In the buy 5 you are multiplying cost by 5 before the calculation, you probably want to do it after. This would still have a problem though, as when buying singles each cost n is based on the previous n-1, but when buying five the cost of n is only based on n-5 calculated 5 times. You need some kind of loop or recursion to calculate the buy 5 price of n for each (n-1 n-2 n-3 n-4 & n-5).

Answer (score 1):

These two are different

```
Math.pow(something * 5, 1.05) / 1.18
Math.pow(something, 1.05) * 5 / 1.18
```

and also doing five time `Math.pow(something, 1.05)/1,18` each time on the result of the precedent one. This latter is the one you need to implement for your purpose I think.